# Why is the EntitySet "owners" not present in Dynamics CRM metadata?

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

Using [odata-client-microsoft-dynamics](https://github.com/davidmoten/odata-client) I'm generating java code as a client for the Dynamics CRM OData api. The basis of the code generation is the metadata defined at https://PROJECT.crm6.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/$metadata?format=xml.

In the metadata I see about 600 *NavigationPropertyBinding* elements that target the EntitySet "owners" but this EntitySet is not defined in the metadata (and there is no import to suggest it is defined elsewhere). To my eyes the metadata is broken, can someone tell me where to find the EntitySet "owners" definition or explain why it's missing from the metadata?

Note that I have confirmed this EntitySet is missing in different organizations' Dynamics CRM metadata including crm4 and crm6, both v9.1.

Comment: Linking related github issue: https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client/issues/625

Comment: Thanks Arun, I still consider it an unanswered question, according to the odata spec the metadata is incomplete. I'll try the question on dynamics crm repos in github.

Comment: sure, I'm curious to know the response you will be receiving there. pls keep this thread posted :)

Comment: @ArunVinoth I looked and see no obvious repo to raise an issue on. Suggestions?

Comment: I will normally create an issue under the appropriate documentation itself, MS people respond there. Probably this one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/web-api-types-operations

Comment: Created an issue at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerapps-docs/issues/1816

Comment: Can you answer this and close it out? :) you may upvote in case my answer helped you

Comment: @ArunVinoth  Your answer still doesn't explain why the specification is not being complied with so I'll leave it open.

Comment: Btw, you said it is not a blocker in GitHub issue. Since it is still open there in github as well for a long time, I thought of getting your workaround documented to help somebody else in the community.

Answer (score 0):

There is no entity called “owner” but it is a special entity reference ([polymorphic lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/types-of-fields?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#different-types-of-lookups)), it can be either `owninguser` or `owningteam`. This is because owner is tightly coupled for Dynamics security concepts - an entity record can be owned by a system user or a team (set of users).

If you are trying to fetch the details using web api, you have to expand both the attributes and one of that will have value based on ownership. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/posts/how-to-retrieve-an-owner-lookup-in-dynamics-365-with-the-webapi)

**Update**:

When you look at these navigation property bindings, the targets like leads, accounts, businessunits are all actual entities referred by plural names. Others are teams and systemusers - they are also actual entities, but internally referred by `Target = "owners"` and either one of the Path will be filled in by platform based on assignment.

```
      <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="originatingleadid" Target="leads" />
      <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="ownerid" Target="owners" />
      <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="owningbusinessunit" Target="businessunits" />
      <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="owningteam" Target="teams" />
      <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="owninguser" Target="systemusers" />
      <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="parentaccountid" Target="accounts" />
```

and the actual property:

```
    <NavigationProperty Name="ownerid" Type="mscrm.principal" Nullable="false" Partner="owner_accounts">
      <ReferentialConstraint Property="_ownerid_value" ReferencedProperty="ownerid" />
    </NavigationProperty>
```

and the partner:

```
    <NavigationProperty Name="owner_accounts" Type="Collection(mscrm.account)" Partner="ownerid" />
```

Note: To explain it better, I referred the above nodes from metadata but they may or may not be from/available in the same entity.

Comment: I'm not looking for an Entity called 'owner' but for an EntitySet called 'owners' which is referenced in 600 places in the metadata. I want to generate a product that can access the whole api as defined by the metadata and the metadata is incomplete. I've dummied up the EntitySet for owners as an empty one with a fake id as a workaround on the assumption that this EntitySet is for internal use. As an example, in terms of api usage the path /accounts/owners/... should be available but there is no definition of the path options for the owners segment.

Comment: @DaveMoten for every entity like account,contact - you will get entity set as accounts, contacts (plural names). Owner/owners is not usual entity/set available to use. The above answer is the explanation for that. Trust me.

Comment: Thanks, there is no magical interpretation of plurals going on though. If the target is 'owners' there should be an entity set, singleton, or containment navigation property called `owners`. See odata spec https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-csdl-xml/v4.01/odata-csdl-xml-v4.01.html#sec_BindingTarget.

Comment: @DaveMoten I cannot comment on odata standards, but I know Dynamics well. You can ask this question in MS twitter handle if you want or in github :)

Comment: Thanks for engaging on this Arun, I appreciate it.